# Fixing HTML5 for IE8

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, web

I cant seem to figure out why the following code does not work properly in IE8, but works perfectly in Chrome. Please advise to any mistakes in the code, or if there is a work-around I could quickly implement.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="description" content="Orlando Cake Balls">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Cake Balls,Cakes Balls,Cake Balls Cake,Orlando Cakes,Cake Pops Recipes,What is a Cake Pop,What is a Cake Ball,Cake,Ball,Cakes,Balls,Orlando,Pops,Recipes,What">
    <meta name="author" content="Joe Quinn">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>ORL Cake Balls</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css" />    
        <!--Google Analytics-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var _gaq = _gaq || [];
          _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36012302-1']);
          _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

          (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
          })();
        </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="emailcontainer">
        <a href="mailto:info@orlandocakeballs.com" title="Contact Us" class="emaillink"></a>

        <div id="socialmedia">
            <div id="twitter">
                <a href="https://twitter.com/ORLCakeBalls/" target="_blank" data-show-count="false"><img src="../twitter-logo.jpg" width="25" height="25" alt="Twitter Link" /></a>
           <!--     <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>  -->
            </div>
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/OrlandoCakeBalls/" target="_blank" id="facebook" title="Like Us"><img src="../facebook-logo.jpg" width="25" height="25" alt="Facebook Link" /></a>
            <a href="http://pinterest.com/orlcakeballs/" target="_blank" id="pinterest" title="Pin Us"><img src="../pinterest-logo.jpg" width="25" height="25" alt="pinterest Link" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
<footer id="copyright">
© 2012 Orlando Cake Balls. All rights reserved.
</footer>

</body>
```

```
body {
background: #fff url(../landingpage.jpg) no-repeat top center;
background-size: auto 900px;
}
#emaillink {
text-decoration: none;
}
#copyright {
padding: 830px 0px 10px 0px;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
font-family: Arial;
}

.emaillink {
position: absolute; 
top: 400px; 
left: 695px; 
width: 290px; 
height: 50px; 
background-color: transparent; 
border: 1px solid #fff; 
}

.emaillink:hover {
position: absolute; 
top: 400px; 
left: 695px; 
width: 290px; 
height: 50px; 
background-color: transparent; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #00BFFF; 
}
#emailcontainer {
width: 900px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}
#twitter {
position: absolute; 
top: 470px; 
left: 720px; 
/*background-color: transparent; 
border: 1px solid #fff; */
}
#twitter:hover {
opacity: 0.4;
filter: alpha (opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

#facebook {
position: absolute; 
top: 470px; 
left: 755px; 
background-color: transparent; 
border: 1px solid #fff; 
}
#facebook:hover {
opacity: 0.4;
filter: alpha (opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

#pinterest {
position: absolute; 
top: 470px; 
left: 790px; 
background-color: transparent; 
border: 1px solid #fff; 
}
#pinterest:hover {
opacity: 0.4;
filter: alpha (opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? How is it not working in IE8?

Comment: The CSS is not working properly. All of the items are on the screen, but displayed incorrectly. The domain is orlandocakeballs.com

Comment: You should really improve your question! What result do you espect? What do you get in IE8 instead? Provide a fiddle and so on...

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail. Its my first question on the site and I assumed that the issue would be obvious enough when the site was opened with IE.

Answer (score 2):

The `background-size` css style (in your body styling) is new in CSS3 and is not supported in IE8 or lower. See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t45.

Comment: What would be the best fix for this?

Comment: Probably, the best fix would be to use an image editor to resize your image instead of css.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider adding `display: block` to the `footer` element.

> But what happens when a browser comes across an element that it doesn’t recognize? We can’t be sure. It might get no styling,
>   it might inherit a some default styling, it might not be displayed at all. Therefore, we make sure that we account for any and
>   all styling of our new elements in our own CSS. No assumptions.

Source: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-make-all-browsers-render-html5-mark-up-correctly-even-ie6/

You could use a [HTML5 reset stylesheet](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/) that does this and much more.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.createElement('header');
 document.createElement('nav');
 document.createElement('menu');
 document.createElement('section');
 document.createElement('article');
 document.createElement('aside');
 document.createElement('footer');
</script>
```